# Store longitude and latitude from google places API

Tags: laravel, google-maps, laravel-5, google-places-api, laravel-5.4

I have a form in laravel where there is google's autocomplete field named as address. There is no map and stores address as New Road, Kathmandu, Nepal. 
I need to obtain its geo coordinates(lat lng) in controller before storing to database. So that I could calculate radius from it and provide information to users about near people.

Comment: You could store lat/long separately and do some heavy queries calculating radius yourself (not efficient when dealing with a lot of records), or utilize the geospatial functionality mysql provides (assuming you use mysql). See https://mikepolatoglou.com/geospatial-mysql-laravel-53 for example.

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tired and show where is the issue. The questions seems too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it when you fill address fields on the form. Following is the code to fill longitude and latitude. And then post the form and calculate radius in your controller.

```
$('#latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
$('#longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
```